# Error importing textures with images, format revit autodesk viewer

Tags: autodesk-viewer

In creating a Revit model, we assign the image elements as material.

The first tree cubes have been assigned predefined images in Revit, the rest external images, which we have downloaded and added to our project.

We have put the images in different ways always incorporating them into the project along with the predefined images of Revit, we have created default materials with our images.

But the viewfinder does not show them.
What can be the problem? We use Revit 2015, Thank you very much for the help.
[image: imagen de revit]
[image: imagen del visor]
[FBX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDfyD.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the [Model Derivative API](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2) & [Viewer](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2) don't support Revit materials based on images (as of Nov, 2016)

Comment: All I show are materials with images. Some materials if they are seen. ¿?

Answer (score 0):

I have heard rumours that you may have better luck exporting from Revit to FBX and then translating that in Forge. Could you please test that, verify whether it helps, and let us know? Thank you!

Comment: We have tested with FBX and it does not display any image. https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDfyD.png